# Does the existence of an action on global sections give an equivariant structure on the bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, complex-geometry, equivariant-maps

Let $L\to X$ be a complex line bundle globally generated by sections.  Suppose that there is action of a lie group $G$ on $\Gamma(X, L)$.

Is there necessarily an equivariant structure on $L$?

Here is my try at trying to get one:

Let $x \in X$, and let $v \in L_x$, and let $s$ be a global section through $v$.  It makes sense to set $gv=(g*s)(g^{-1}x)$:

(after all if one already had an equivariant structure on $L$ then the action of $g$ on a section $s$, namely $g*s$, is supposed to be given by $gs(gx)=g*s$).

What has to be checked to see if this gives a well defined action on the total space of $L$ is that if $t$ is another section s.t. $t(x)=v$, then $(g*t)(g^{-1}x)=gv=(g*s)(g^{-1}x)$.

> Is this true for some relatively trivial assumptions on $X$, $G$ and
>   $L$?(I would also be happy for easy counter examples).

Comment: I don't know of the answer to this question but at least the answer to   the question I am really interested in is negative.  The question is"Does every group action on the space of sections arise from an equivariant structure on the bundle that has already been specified on the base space".  If the answer was yes then one could consider the case where the action on the base space is transitive.  Then the trivial action on the space of sections would arise from an action on the total space of the line bundle.  But then the line bundle would have to be trivial.  Contradiction.

Comment: Indeed my assignment above in my question only makes sense if the action on $X$ has already been given.  So the only question that it makes sense to ask is the one in the comment above.